# changing scatter' scale affect its working logic - Kivy

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to change the size of a scatter so it can be same size as the element of the grid i am putting the scatter in.

For that i found that the way to change Scatter size is scale so here what i did :

```
    gridscreen = GridLayout(rows = x-2)
        for y in self.listim:

            scatt = Scatter()
            scatt.scale = 2.5

            image = Image(source = y)
            scatt.add_widget(image)

            gridscreen.add_widget(scatt)
```

The result is not quiet what i expected, because the size of every Scatter created is good, but the Scatter don't work same as before (before i add `scatt.scale = 2.5`) now, not all the Image in the Scatter are connected, especially thoses in the Y axis:

Only translation on x axis are allowed, so it seems that my problem come from `scatt.do_translation_y`, but i didn't found a way to solve this problem.

I hope i did explain well my problem.

Thank you for your time ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the scatter will be defined by the layout - in your case the GridLayout- so whats left is only to make the image size the same as the scatter - something like this

In the kv file:

```
<ScatterWithImage>:
     src: "some_path"
     Image:
         size: root.size
         stretch: True
         source: root.src
```

In the python file:

```
 class ScatterWithImage(Scatter):
     src = StringProperty("some_path_to_an_image")
 gridlayout.add_widget(ScatterWithImage(src=y))
```

Comment: I just tested it, it perfectly work !! Thank you very much !! :D